# Django Deprecation: Signals

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-signals

Will signals be deprecated? I'm starting a new application and I initially planned to implement some  signal based functions but a colleague told me that signals are about to be deprecated and that I should refrain from using them. 
Is that true? I haven't been able to find any sources that support his claim.

Comment: The deprecation timeline (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/internals/deprecation/) does not mention that, so as far as we know, these are not deprecated. But signals are overused in general. Usually signals should be used as one of the last resorts. Especially since a lot of Django ORM calls circumvent signals.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem okay, thank you! What practices would you generally recommend before resorting to a signal? I will need to implement notification for users.

Comment: usually then it might be better to do that in the view. Especially since signals have no request context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> but a colleague told me that signals are about to be deprecated and that I should refrain from using them. Is that true?

That might of course be the case in the (far) future. But the current [*Django Deprecation Timeline* [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/internals/deprecation/) does not mention this. The only thing with respect to signals that has been removed is the `weak` parameter in the `disconnect` function.

That being said, Django's signals are often used when it is not necessary. Several Django ORM calls, like [**`bulk_create(..)`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#bulk-create) for example *circumvent* the signals. It thus gives a false idea that some task will be performed when creating new records. see for example [this blog post [Lincoln Loop]](https://lincolnloop.com/blog/django-anti-patterns-signals/) that explains why signals are often not a good idea.